# Conditional load using data file in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-loadfile

I am trying to load a file with a condition using mysql

```
GIFTCARDS (table):
    id| store    | amount   | 
    1 | starbucks|          | 
    2 | target   |          | 
    3 | starbucks|          | 
    4 | target   |          | 
    5 | target   |          | 
    6 | target   |          | 

winning.txt (file)
25
10
15
```

I need to assign "amount" randomly. 
Please note that there are 4 rows with "target" but winning file contains 3 rows. This means there will be one "target" row, selected randomly, that will have amount null. Amount for each Starbucks card will be loaded using a separate file.

Is it possible to do so using a mysql query?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but you may be interested in Rand() function MySQL have and can be used even in INSERT or UPDATE statements. More on: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load `winning.txt` into `winning` (a table) using `load data infile`.

You can then do the rest in a MySQL query.  The key is to enumerate the rows and do a `join`:

```
update giftcards gc join
       (select @rn := @rn + 1 as x, id
        from giftcards cross join
             (@rn := 0) vars
        where store = 'target'
       ) gcx
       on gc.id = gcx.id join
       (select @rnw := @rnw + 1) as x, amount
        from winning cross join
             (select @rnw := 0) vars
       ) w
       on gcx.x = w.x
    set gc.amount = w.amount;
```